# Can women ask for male hoor al ayn?

Tags: women, jannah, men, hereafter

So i know that men get hoor al ayn in jannah and women don’t due to their natural fitra, however if a woman was so desire a male hoor al ayn would it be possible for her since allah is the all-giver?

Answer (score 1):

Allah will reduce her wish to get male Hoor type someone. But there is no Authentic or even weak source of Hadith/Quran to confirm that a Muslim woman will get another Husband. No proof of that.
But rather it is mentioned in Hadith that if a woman has multiple husbands in this World(by marrying another man after one husband's Death), she will get only her Last husband or the Husband whose behavior was the best. Even if her husbands continue to die and she remarries again and again, even if she has 10 Husbands in this way in 10 different times on Earth, she will get only 1 Husband in Jannah.